# Multiple AJAX calls return JSON objects in random order

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to store the JSON objects returned like this

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="LIVE"></div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="past-matches"></div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="upcoming-matches"></div>
```

using the following script.

```
$(function() {
query=["select * from cricket.scorecard.live.summary","select * from      cricket.past_matches", "select * from cricket.upcoming_matches"]
container=[".LIVE",".past-matches",".upcoming-matches"]
container_no=0
query_no=0;
for( var section=0;section<query.length;section++)
{   
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",        
        jsonp: "callback",         
        dataType: "jsonp",        
        data: {
            q: query[query_no++],
            env:"store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0",           
            format: "json"
        },       
        // Work with the response
        success: function(data ) {
             console.log( data ); // The problem: returns JSON objects in different order everytime the page reloads

             //I would like to store data like this
             if(container_no>0)
             {  
                if(container_no==1)
                {   $(container[container_no]).append('<p>recent match data</p>');
                    container_no++; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $(container[container_no]).append('<p>upcoming match data</p>');
                     container_no++; 
                }                   
            }   
            else{
               $(container[container_no]).append('<p>live match data</p>');
               container_no++;
            }
        }
    });
   }    
 });
```

The problem is JSON objects are returned in different order every time the page is reloaded, so I can't save the data in the right div. I think I made a mistake involving variable scope. 
here's the fiddle:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jackhammer94/y7akegqa/%22FIDDLE%22)

Comment: Fiddle isn't working.

Comment: either make a single call to return all data, or synchronize the data results. you can wait til all the calls come back and then act.

Comment: @HugoSousa use the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous (that's what the "A" stands for in Ajax).  Thus, they have an indeterminate time to execute and when you execute multiple Ajax calls, there is no guaranteed order that the results will arrive.

So, if you want to know which result is which (e.g. which is the first, the second and so on), you have to create a counter which is unique for each ajax call.  One way to do that is to put each Ajax call into a function call and pass a counter into that function call.  This function will create a closure and the counter will be maintained for you when the results come back.

Here's a version using a function that comes from using `.forEach()` to iterate your query array.  I've also made several other modifications to simplify the code:

```
$(function() {
    var query = ["select * from cricket.scorecard.live.summary", "select * from      cricket.past_matches", "select * from cricket.upcoming_matches"];
    var container = [".LIVE", ".past-matches", ".upcoming-matches"];
    var msg = ['<p>live match data</p>', '<p>recent match data</p>', '<p>upcoming match data</p>'];
    query.forEach(function(queryVal, cnt) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
            jsonp: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: queryVal,
                env: "store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0",
                format: "json"
            },
            // Work with the response
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(container[cnt]).append(msg[cnt]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here's another version that creates an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) to solve the same problem:

```
$(function() {
    var query = ["select * from cricket.scorecard.live.summary", "select * from      cricket.past_matches", "select * from cricket.upcoming_matches"];
    var container = [".LIVE", ".past-matches", ".upcoming-matches"];
    for (var section = 0; section < query.length; section++) {
        // add IIFE so we can capture the section number uniquely for each ajax call
        (function(cnt) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                jsonp: "callback",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: query[cnt],
                    env: "store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0",
                    format: "json"
                },
                // Work with the response
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var msg;
                    if (cnt === 0) {
                        msg = '<p>live match data</p>'
                    } else if (cnt === 1) {
                        msg = '<p>recent match data</p>';
                    } else {
                        msg = '<p>upcoming match data</p>';
                    }
                    $(container[cnt]).append(msg);
                }
            });
        })(section);
    }
});
```

Note, I also added `var` to all your local variables so you are not accidentally created global variables.

---

If you actually want to wait until ALL results are collected so you can then add them exactly in your loop order, then you can use jQuery's `$.when()` to do that.

```
$(function() {
    var query = ["select * from cricket.scorecard.live.summary", "select * from      cricket.past_matches", "select * from cricket.upcoming_matches"];
    var container = [".LIVE", ".past-matches", ".upcoming-matches"];
    var msg = ['<p>live match data</p>', '<p>recent match data</p>', '<p>upcoming match data</p>'];
    var promises = [];
    query.forEach(function(queryVal, cnt) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
            jsonp: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: queryVal,
                env: "store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0",
                format: "json"
            },
        }));
    }
    // wait for all ajax results to be done
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            // iterate all results in order
            console.log(arguments[i][0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, the same problem continues to exist.http://jsfiddle.net/jackhammer94/y7akegqa/1/

Comment: @user3832512 - what problem?  The results may arrive in any order, but the code puts them in the proper place.  If you truly want to only add the results visually in a particular order, then that is a different problem.  This puts each result where it belongs regardless of which order they arrive in.  I can also add a way to do that, though I'm not sure why you need to do it that way.

Comment: @user3832512 - I added a version at the end that actually waits for all results to be returned before iterating over the results.